# How do I ensure a row is inserted once when multiple threads attempt simultaneously?

Tags: sql

I have a table and multiple processes are running, at 8pm a row should be inserted into the database. All the processes will detect when it's 8pm and attempt to insert the row, but only one row should be inserted.

I am wondering how to ensure it is inserted only once.

So for example it will do (pseudosql):

```
select * from myTable where criteria=something

if no results, insert into myTable values criteria=something
```

And this will potentially be executed multiple times simultaneously.

Is there a simple way to ensure that if there is already a record with `criteria=something` that the insert will do nothing?

Essentially putting the above pseudocode into a transaction that blocks anything else from even doing a select would work, because the 2nd transaction would have to wait for the first before it even did the first select, and that would ensure the first select would return a result... but it seems... tacky!

Sadly I can't use a unique constraint because there will be times when multiple entries will be present but with a 'failed' or 'processed' flag set.

Answer (score -1):

Your pseudo-SQL is subject to a race condition, so it will not ensure uniqueness. Most databases have a concept called *unique constraint* that exists specifically for this purpose. After the transaction that is the first to the party inserts the row, all other transactions will get exceptions when trying to insert the same data, so it's just a matter of gracefully handling these exceptions.